# How to perform automatic typecasting for non-ActiveRecord backed classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, types, casting

I have an `ActiveRecrod` model `User` and a separate class `UsersFilter`, which is solely used for filtering the model. Say `UsersFilter` accepts a parameter hash `params = {min_age: '18', max_age: '30', admin: 'true'}`. All the values are strings. If I pass these values directly to `ActiveRecord`, the queries will work. However, I also want to be able to use these values in my code, so that I can build some logic around it. So in order to do that, I need to manually type cast these values. So `UsersFilter` might look like this:

```
class UsersFilter
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

  attr_accessor :min_age, :max_age, :admin

  def initialize(params)
    params[:min_age] = params[:min_age].to_i
    params[:max_age] = params[:min_age].to_i
    params[:admin] = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(params[:admin])

    assign_attributes(params)
  end

  # some query methods
end
```

So my question is - is there a rails module I can mix in in order to have this typecasting occur automatically?

P.S. I suppose, I will need to add a mapping between each attribute and its type.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any Rails module you could mix-in (there was no for Rails 4.2 and below) but you can take a look at [dry-types](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-types/) gem that allows to define types and value coercions for your classes

Answer (score 1):

Use custom setters:

```
class UsersFilter
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def min_age=(age)
   self[:min_age] = age.to_i
  end

  def max_age=(age)
   self[:max_age] = age.to_i
  end

  def admin(val)
   self[:admin] = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(val)
  end
end
```

If you really need to dry it out to a generic typecasting facility you could use `define_method` to do it with metaprogramming. But [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a nice one, but still - it just moves the logic from the initialize method, to the setter methods. I was hoping there is something like [active_type](https://github.com/makandra/active_type), but built into Rails.